# How to create a network with LTE base station and dynamic creation/deletion of car fog nodes?

Tags: omnet++, veins-lte

I am trying to implement a [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8489874/authors#authors) where the architecture is an urban cell having zone head as LTE base station that allocates tasks dynamically to mobile fog nodes which are cars. The cars are connected to LTE base station as they enter the cell and the zone head keeps track of when they are going to leave the cell. Each car also interacts with its neighbour cars using DSRC (one-hop communication) to know which car nodes are in its proximity.

I don't know which package to use to set up this architecture and how to set up it.
The package used in the paper in VeinsLTE but I cannot find enough help for getting started.
Please enlist some references or getting started with a vehicular fog network.
Or please tell me what steps should I take to build this architecture.

Answer (score 2):

VeinsLTE was a project that allowed SimuLTE to be used with Veins. In more recent versions of SimuLTE and Veins, neither needs additional modifications to work with each other. If you want to give it a try, you can simply download an [Instant Veins](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/instant-veins/) version that already includes SimuLTE.